# Jquery accordion with sub navigation controlling slider issue

Tags: jquery, navigation, slider, accordion, carousel

I have a jquery accordion menu that works just fine and is combined with a carousel slider.  The original code that I am working from has the h3 element as the slider trigger and simply slides to a new image when an accordion menu item is selected.

The working version has the accordion menu item listed like this:

```
<h3 data-index="0"><a href="#">FACILITIES</a></h3> 
<div> 
    <a href="subnav_page1.html" >
      <p>Sub nav item 1</p>
      </a>
</div>
```

The problem I am having now is that the client wishes to have sub navigation in each of the accordion menu items control the slider and for the life of me, I can't figure out a way to have the sub nav trigger the slider.

I have tried a variety of code similar to this:

```
<h3><a href="">TECHNOLOGY</a></h3> 
<div>
     <h666 data-index="1"><a href="#">Rockets For Power Generation</a></h666>
     <h666 data-index="2"><a href="#">Platelets</a></h666>
     <h666 data-index="3"><a href="#">Gas Generator</a></h666>
     <h666 data-index="4"><a href="#">Turbines</a></h666>
</div>
```

I have created a new class to format the sub navigation menu items, but nothing I have tried is allowing the sub nav to trigger the slider.

Here is the page I am working on:

[Accordion Slider](http://tinyurl.com/6ukb3nn)

You will see that the bottom accordion buttons trigger the slider, but the sub nav in the first accordion menu are not doing anything.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!!

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

If you investigate [the HTML the plugin depends on to function properly](http://www.geertdedeckere.be/shop/accordionza/download/accordion3/demo.html), it looks nothing like what you have in your page.

My quick glance at the options suggests that what you're trying to achieve isn't directly possible with this plugin.  I suggest contacting its developer, using a different plugin altogether, or rolling your own accordion.